# Присвоение в описании класса

Tags: c++, классы

В какой момент времени во время исполнения произойдет присвоение int a = 5?

```
class B {
private:
   int a = 5;
public:
   B();
   ~B();
}
```

Comment: Чтобы понимать как оно работает на самом деле, полезно смотреть ассемблерный код, который генерирует компилятор [https://gcc.godbolt.org/](https://gcc.godbolt.org/). Не нужно понимать его досконально, но разобраться с порядком вызова функций и других операций (не забывая о UB) поможет.

Comment: @free_ze: Преждевременное бросание в разглядывание ассемблерного кода как правило порождает необоснованные домыслы, не имеющие никакого отношения к реальной семантике языка. Сначала имеет смысл изучить хотя бы основы теории, чтобы было понятно, что именно компилятор пытается реализовать.

Comment: @AnT, безусловно, все это лишь с опорой на Стандарт. Ассемблерные листинги - это лишь инструмент, если применять его с головой, то "преждевременность" лишь пойдет на пользу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это никакое не "присвоение". Это *инициализатор* и использоваться он будет для *инициализации* `B::a`, а не для присваивания. Альтернативной (и эквивалентной) формой записи будет

```
class B {
  ...
  int a{ 5 };
  ...
};
```

Этот инициализатор будет использован для *инициализации по умолчанию* этого члена класса *в конструкторах* этого класса. Если вы "забудете" явно проинициализировать `B::a` в списке инициализации конструктора класса `B`

```
B::B() // Инициализация для `a` отсутствует
  {}
```

то `B::a` будет неявно проинициализировано значением `5`. Как будто кто-то за вас тихонько написал

```
B::B() : a(5) 
  {}
```

Если же вы сами явно проинициализируете `B::a` в конструкторе

```
B::B() : a(42) 
  {}
```

то указанный вами выше инициализатор `5` будет просто проигнорирован.

У вас в классе `B` может быть много разных конструкторов. Какие-то из них могут явно инициализировать `B::a`, а какие-то - не делать явной инициализации для `B::a`. В последнем случае в дело будет вступать ваше `5`

```
class B 
{
private:
   int a = 5;
public:
   B(int) : a(42) // Здесь есть явная инициализация `a`
   {
     // Здесь `a` равно 42
   }

   B(double)      // Здесь нет явной инициализации `a`
   {
     // Здесь `a` равно 5
   }
};
```

---

Функциональность таких инициализаторов не сводится только к конструкторам. Они учитываются и в "бесконструкторных" формах инициализации. Например, если класс является *агрегатом* и инициализируется при помощи *агрегатной инициализации*, то такие инициализаторы тоже принимаются во внимание компилятором

```
struct S
{
  int x;
  int y = 42;
  int z;
};
...
S s = { 5 }; // Агрегатная инициализация 
// Здесь `s.x` равно 5, `s.y` равно 42, `s.z` равно 0
```